# How to push an item to an array in redux without creating a duplicate

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have a few inputs for which I'm getting values and setting to redux state and at onClick sending them to api.

Here are inputs and checkboxes

```
FormInput(label="Name" placeholder="" onChange=event => this.props.getValue(event.target.value, 'FIRST_NAME'))

FormInput(label="Last Name" placeholder="" onChange=event => this.props.getValue(event.target.value, 'LAST_NAME'))

CheckBox(label="A" onClick=event => this.props.getValue(event.target.checked, 'A'))

CheckBox(label="B" onClick=event => this.props.getValue(event.target.checked, 'B'))
```

At on change and onClick i'm passing values to redux state via one redux action.

For making things simple and updating redux state via just one onChange handler I used :

```
function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return {
    getValue: bindActionCreators(getValue, dispatch),
  };
}
```

It's my redux action.

It's getting values from all inputs and checkboxes and passing them to redux state.

Here is action type. I'm passing it like a parameter from inputs, this way I keep my action minimal, so, not using different actions for all inputs instead just using one handler function for all.

```
export const getValue = (value, type) => {
  return dispatch => {
    console.log(value)
    dispatch({
      type: 'SET_' + type,
      payload: value
    });
  };
};
```

and here's my reducer:

```
import {
  SET_FIRST_NAME,
  SET_LAST_NAME,
  SET_A,
  SET_B
} from "Store/Types/Form/";

let initialState = {
    firsName: null,
    lastName: null,
    options: [
        {
            id: 1,
            name: "selection A",
            selection: false,
        },
        {
            id: 1,
            name: "selection B",
            selection: false,
        }
    ]
};

export default (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case SET_FIRST_NAME:
      return { ...state, firsName: action.payload };
    case SET_LAST_NAME:
      return { ...state, lastName: action.payload };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

In my initial state options array I want to pass values from checkboxes so **SET_A** and **SET_B** and that's how I want my object to look.

How I can pass my values how I want and how can I prevent duplicating if I use push?

If everything works I will just pass my redux state to app directly.

Comment: sounds like [You Might Not Need Redux](https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/you-might-not-need-redux-be46360cf367), but assuming you simplified the code only for the question - what is the problem you experienced when duplicating the array? redux needs non-mutating data to work as documented, so using `push` will open your code to various potential bugs that are hard to investigate

Comment: I need redux it's good for keep state in one place and accessing from everywhere. So if not push how i can do that?

Comment: similar to https://redux.js.org/basics/example

Answer (score 0):

So you shouldn't push to state directly since it's supposed to be immutable. but you can use produce from immer to clone state. This was you can change the cloned object and reassign state object